# Identify Fantasy book series I started to read in the late 80's early 90's

Tags: story-identification

Sorry for the vagueness of the following description but I can only remember some of the info on the book, my high school days were a blur.

The series was set in a somewhat [Renaissance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance) type period where some characters had the ability to drain powers/life from others. The Church of the time was against it and they had to keep hidden. One of the main characters I remember was missing a hand and would push his stump against people when he pulled their power.

It was a multi-book series and I only started on the first book before I got distracted (was easy in those days!) and had to take it back to the library. I think at that time I found the Pern series and got totally distracted with them and never picked it back up again.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? For example, anything else about the protagonists?

Comment: Not a whole lot... unfortunately the only character I remember is the one with the missing hand and I truly can't remember if he was the main character or not. I remember that some with the power were actually in the Church and were not able to admit it. The power was not exclusive to nobles, some nobles had it some lower born had it. I am embarrassed I can't remember more. I remember it was a little above my comprehension level at the time and that was one of the reasons I pulled away from it even though I enjoyed it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say roughly what year it was when you read this, did the book seem old when you read it, maybe what the cover was like, and was it hardback or paperback.

Comment: Could it be the Deryni series by Katherine Kurtz?  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deryni_novels)  Not really draining life/powers, but the Deryni race has magical abilities and somewhere in the series a few of them can "turn off" the power of others.  The magic and race are considered heretics by the church, but a few are active clergy and trying to get that overturned.  Don't remember anyone without a hand, but could be in there.

Comment: @eshier -- Deryni was my first thought also.  Tavis, Javan's healer, has his hand cut off.  He works later with a hand and a stump; it is described in at least one place how he pushes his stump against or into an injury, if I remember correctly.  It doesn't look like we'll see the OP again around here; he hasn't visited in years, so we may not find out if this is what he is looking for.